# Bit magnetic in one handle, but not another

Tags: electromagnetism

Notice that the driver bit in this video is magnetically attracted to both handles, yet it is magnetically attracted to the fastener only when it is in the green handle:
[Video on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Flt3.jpg).

[Video description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Flt3.jpg):

1. Driver bit is in black handle. It is magnetically attracted to the handle, but not to a screw.
2. Driver bit is moved to green handle. It is magnetically attracted to the handle and also to the screw.
3. Driver bit is moved back to black handle. It is magnetically attracted to the handle, but not to the screw, just as before.

My 13 year old daughter noticed the phenomenon. Today she'll hopefully learn not only about magnetism, but also discover the amazing results of asking in the right place after showing that [she tried](https://science.howstuffworks.com/magnet.htm) [to research](https://www.first4magnets.com/tech-centre-i61/frequently-asked-questions-i69) [by herself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array).

### Why is the bit attracted to the screw only when in a specific handle?

Note that the screw is magnetically attracted to both handles, though to the green handle far more strongly. The screw is not attracted to the bit when the bit is not in a handle. The bit is magnetically attracted to both handles, it is not only friction holding the bit in place (this is demonstrated in the video).

Comment: Is the fastener attracted by both handles when no driver bit is inserted? I would assume only the green handle will attract the fastener. It does not seem to me the black handle is magnetized. What keeps the driver bit in the black handle is only the friction, but I might easily be wrong about this.. Kudos for your daughter trying to understand what she observes :)

Comment: @MarkoGulin: Thank you, I've added that information to the question. In fact, both handles are magnetic but one moreso.

Comment: That could be your answer - magnetic field produced by the black handle is just not strong enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the black handle retains the bit using a magnet that is mounted sideways with two pole pieces (NS) - so that the bit 'closes the magnetic circuit'; whereas the green handle just has a simple magnet mounted axially (N)?

If this were the case then with the black handle there would be less induced magnetism in the part of the bit touching the screw.

[image: sketch of hypothetical magnet orientation]

Comment: This might be, thank you. How would we check that? Looking at the two handles there is nothing really obviously magnet-related to see. Would a [Magnetic field viewing film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_viewing_film) help?

Comment: @dotancohen I'm not sure how you could check without disassembling the handle. However, if you have a small permanent magnet and something to use as pole pieces (cutlery?), you could demonstrate the effect to your daughter :-)

Comment: Note that with the green handle, the flux return path would probably be via the steel body of the tool - but I omitted that for clarity.